# Magento 2.3 - REST API - Fetch first n order

Tags: sales-order, rest-api, magento2.3.1

I need to fetch the first **n** order with status **processing** or any other.

Does anyone know the API string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the string as below.
I have used **searchCriteria[pageSize]** and **searchCriteria[currentPage]** to fetch first n order and also can fetch page wise order.

```
$pageSize = 100; // magento will create order table with 100 orders in a page
$currentPage = 1; // first page
$ch = curl_init("https://yourhost.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders?searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=processing&searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq&searchCriteria[pageSize]={$pageSize}&searchCriteria[currentPage]={$currentPage}&fields=items[increment_id,status,base_tax_amount,grand_total,base_subtotal,items,billing_address,payment,created_at]");
```

I have added a **fields** parameter by which I can fetch the minimum data of order.

Answer (score 1):

For Get Order Collection using **REST API** with status **processing**, You can pass below request url to fetch order data from Magento.

```
https://yourhost.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders/?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=processing&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq
```

**Method: GET**

**Authorization Token: Admin Token**

**OR**

**My Curl method:**

```
$userData = array("username" => "adminuser", "password" => "adminpassowrd");
$ch = curl_init("https://yourhost.com/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData))));

$token = curl_exec($ch);

$apiOrderUrl = 'https://yourhost.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders/?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=status&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=processing&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=eq';
$ch = curl_init($apiOrderUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$results = json_decode($result, true); // all orders with status pending

foreach ($results['items'] as $order) {
     $commentData = array(
        'id' => $order['entity_id'], //order_id
        'statusHistory' => array(
            'comment' => 'Received order?',
            'entity_id' => null,
            'is_customer_notified' => '1',
            'created_at' => now(),
            'parent_id' => $order['entity_id'], //order_id
            'entity_name' => 'order',
            'status' => 'processing', //assign new status to order
            'is_visible_on_front' => '1'
        )
    );

    $commentData = json_encode($commentData,true);
    $orderStatusApiUrl = 'https://yourhost.com/index.php/rest/V1/orders/'.$order['entity_id'].'/comments';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$orderStatusApiUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $commentData );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($token)));
    $response = curl_exec($ch); //true
}
```

Comment: This code is fetching all orders of 'processing' status. I need only first n order with status 'processing'. Please check my answer.

Comment: @JigarDhaduk: Yes, It will also work..I have provide you a example so you can mentioned searchCriteria filter according to your requirements.